# Unable to search ebay on the Ubuntu Touch default browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

Is there a setting that I need to activate or something that I need to download/install to be able to search ebay on the Ubuntu Touch default browser? As when I try and search I get the following message; 'The eBay mobile website is no longer supported on this device. Access all your eBay activity from your desktop or a supported Apple, Android or Blackberry mobile device.'

Comment: Same here, only just noticed that. Laughed issue I think.

Comment: I have downloaded most of the apps/web apps in the Ubuntu Store and there is the same issue/error message.

Comment: I have logged this in Launchpad under the following bug repeat https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1621630 Please feel free to add comments or mark it as affecting you, if it is.

Comment: Latest update on those big is that it is a duplicate of. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1575780